# HOW to Play HLS with HTML5

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, m3u8

So i'm trying to play HLS streams on HTML5 without using Flash. We've tried many video players but they all relay on a flash player. My question, is it possible to play HLS streams (any) on HTML5 without using Flash?

(I know of the https://github.com/RReverser/mpegts but it doesn't work on mobile and is pretty laggy.)

Comment: which player did you use to play it?
device?
ios version?
you can provide mediainfo?

Comment: What encoding format in your video? Check codec https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html

Answer (score 0):

> m3u8 file is for live streaming. so please play your url in **AVPlayer**
>   https://developer.apple.com/streaming/